Does a positive non-homogeneous term imply that a solution to the associated boundary value problem has a positive average?
I came across this question while researching higher order boundary value problems. It is interesting because there is no maximum principle for higher order boundary value problems. Given this, I'm looking for positive averages (as the next best thing).
Let $U$ be a bounded, smooth domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$; let $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth, non-negative function; and let $\Delta^2$ be the biharmonic differential operator. Consider the following boundary value problem
$$
\Delta^2 u(x) = f(x) \quad x \in U,
$$
$$
u(x)= 0 \quad x \in  \partial U,
$$
$$
(\nabla u \cdot \mathbf{n})(x)= 0 \quad x \in \partial U.
$$
Let $u_f$ be the unique solution of the above boundary value problem. Let $G(x,y)$ be the Green's function associated with $U$, $\Delta^2$, and the above boundary conditions. Does it follow that $\int_U u_f(x) \, dx \geq 0$ for all non-negative functions $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ if $\int_U G(x,y) \, dy \geq 0$ for all $x \in U$?

Please, use descriptive titles. "Is there an error in this proof?" says nothing about the subject of the question.

First note that we have
\begin{equation}
\int_U u_{f}(x) \,dx = \int_{U} ( \int_U f(y) G(x,y) \, dy )\,  dx.
\end{equation}
Invoking the symmetry of $G(x,y)$, we can write
\begin{equation} 
\int_U u_{f}(x) \, dx = \int_{U} (\int_U f(y) G(y,x) \, dy) \, dx.
\end{equation}
We can now use Fubini's Theorem to obtain
\begin{equation}
\int_U u_{f}(x) \, dx = \int_{U} ( \int_U  f(y) G(y,x) \, dx) \, dy.
\end{equation}
This, in turn, allows us to write
\begin{equation}\label{eq}
\int_U u_{f}(x) \, dx = \int_{U} f(y) ( \int_U  G(y,x) \, dx) \, dy.
\end{equation}
Now, suppose that $\int_U G(x,y) \, dy \geq 0$ for all $x \in U$. This, in turn, allows us to conclude that $\int_U G(y,x) \, dx \geq 0$ for all $y \in U$. Since $f$ is non-negative, we can now conclude that the right hand side of the above equation is non-negative. This, in turn, allows us to write $\int_U u_f(x) \, dx \geq 0$.
